# Could not process parameters: builtin_function_or_method(<built-in function id>), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

Tags: python

Brand new to Python/MySQL (and programming!). Creating program to store nutritional content of foods. Then daily create a table of food consumed that will manipulate the values in the food table. Successfully created routines to add, inspect and delete foods. Now trying to extract one food from food table and get the above error. Herewith code:

```
import mysql.connector

def get_foods_detail(category):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='nutrition',
                                             user='root',
                                             password='631150#?ioB')

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_select_query = """select * from foods where category = %s"""
        # set variable in query
        cursor.execute(sql_select_query, (category,))
        # fetch result
        record = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in record:
            print("Id  ", row[0], "CATEGORY:  ", category.rstrip(), "TYPE:  ", row[2
                  ], "BRAND: ", row[3], "SELLER: ", row[4], "Kcal: ", row[7])                                                      
                       
        choose = input("Input id of food consumed ")
        choose = int(choose)
        choose = [choose]
        print(choose)
        sql_select_query = """ select * from foods where id = choose"""
        cursor.execute(sql_select_query,(id))
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print(record)
        user_input = ("Correct record? y/n") **This is as far as I've got**
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to get record from MySQL table: {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

category = input("Enter Food Category: ")
get_foods_detail(category)
```

Expecting the record for the inputted id to display so the user can check it's the right one.
Have tried to interpret possible solutions on the web, and tried all sorts of playing with brackets, etc. Spent whole morning on this - now stuck,
Assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say without detailed error traceback, but, you don't define `id` anywhere (and you shouldn't - it is a built-in Python function. What do you expect `id` to be?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually parameterize your query. Instead of the hard-coded string `choose` in the SQL query, you should have some placeholder:

```
sql_select_query = """ select * from foods where id = %s"""
```

Now, when you execute the query, the second argument to `execute` should be a *tuple* constructed from `choose`:

```
choose = int(input("Input id of food consumed "))
cursor.execute(sql_select_query, (choose,))
```

(Note the trailing common; `(choose)` equivalent to `choose`, and `execute` *must* have some sort of iterable, even if the query only has one placeholder to fill.)

(I know in your original code you redefined `choose = [choose]` to create an iterable, but it's clearer to not reuse names like this. The *choice* is an integer; make the tuple/list/etc explicit in the call to `execute`.)

Comment: I  understand your post, but I get the same error message after changing the code.

Comment: Sorry, error message now:  Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: Solved by creating a new function to select the specific food required.